# PHP Asynchronous HTTP request with response

Tags: php, http, asynchronous

I need to make about 10 requests in my script, and combine their responses. However, if I do it by calling `get_file_contents` 10 times, it works much slower than for example calling `$.json` 10 times in Javascript. I tried looking for ways to make asynchronous http requests in PHP, but every single piece of information I found started with "I don't need the response", which is not my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**file_get_contents** is a synchronous function, so when you call it 10 times, you call it 10 times sequentially. You need to make requests in parallel. [curl_multi_* methods family](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php) is probably what you are looking for. If you are not familiar with curl enough it may be tricky to implement it correctly, so I'd recommend you to use some library for that.

You can take a look at this library https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl

Comment: Looks good enough, is it also smart enough to only do the SSL handshake once?